# Cross join on subquery

Tags: sql, cross-join

Fee Table

```
FeeId(PK)managerId    amount    Type    
1        50           100       1
1        50           10000     39
1        50           50000     2
1        50           50000     3
1        50           50000     4
```

Manager Table

```
FeeId(FK)Split    managerId
1        70       68
```

Desired Results:

```
FeeId    managerId    amount    Type    
1        50           30        1
1        68           70        1
1        50           3000      39
1        68           7000      39
1        50           15000     2
1        68           35000     2
1        50           15000     3
1        68           35000     3
1        50           15000     4
1        68           35000     4
```

This dataset is just one record, there are many more FeeId's in my data. A cross join would not take this into account. I basically want to cross join each manager based on the feeId.

The amount column is then recalculated to 70,30 for managerid 68,50 respectivly.

How do I do a cross join on each subset: WHERE f.feeId = m.feeId to get the desired results?

Example of cross join with incorrect results since the manager table will have more then 1 fee:

```
SELECT 
    f.feeId,
    (cast(m.split as decimal) / 100) * f.amount as amount
FROM
    dbo.fee f
    CROSS JOIN dbo.manager m
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for?

Comment: @Goat_CO SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 3):

As I understand this problem, you are trying to allocate the amount in `fee` between the two managers.  The following query does this by cross joining an additional table, which is used to choose the data for each row.

```
select f.feeid,
       (case when n.n = 1 then f.managerid
             when n.n = 2 then m.managerid
        end) as managerid,
       (case when n.n = 1 then f.amount * (100 - m.split)/100
             when n.n = 2 then f.amount * m.split/100
        end) as amount, f.type
from fee f cross join
     manager m cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2) as n;
```

As a comment, this seems like a very unusual data structure.

Comment: It is a bit unusual, but I think once you understand the data structure it makes sense. The Fee table is a tall table and already has one manager. We don't change the raw data from the source but rather give the user on our end the ability to add another manager and split the amount by a percent. There are currently 504 managers that need to be applied to the Fee table. Hence my question, since doing a straight out cross join would apply all 504 managers to all fees.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this should work:

```
SELECT   f.feeId, ,f.managerID, (cast(m.split as decimal) / 100) * f.amount as amount, f.type
FROM fee f
JOIN manager m
ON f.FeeID = m.FeeID
AND f.managerID = m.managerID
```

Comment: I think what you're missing is that the managerId does not join on anything. But I want the manager (based on FeeId) to cross join to the Fee table.